# C# How correctly work get and set?

Tags: c#, list, get

I am beginner in programming and I want to ask you probably the easiest question.
I did something like this:

```
class person
{
    private string name;
    public string surname;
    private int year;       
}

class student : person
{

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<student> list = new List<student>();

        list.Add(new student()
            {
                surname = "jordan"
            //    name ... ???
            //    year .. ?
            });
    }
}
```

How can I correctly use `get` and `set` if I have `private` field or how can I assign a value to `name` or `year`?

Comment: There is no other way if I want private fields?

Comment: You could create properties, or set them from a constructor.  Also public fields are considered bad form, you should prefer public properties instead.

Comment: Run, don't walk, and buy CLR Via C#.  Skip the first two chapters and start reading.  You'll thank me.

Comment: Fixed typos. Changed formatting ("bla" -> `bla`).

Answer (score 0):

(Note the use of Upper case for classes and properties, lower case reserved for fields and local variables).

Declare as `public` [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) like so:

```
class Person
{
    public string Surname {get; set;}
}
```

Usage:

```
new Person{
   Surname = "jordan"
};
```

Or with `private` setters, and set in constructor.

```
class Person
{
    public Person(string surname)
    {
       Surname = surname;
    }

    public string Surname {get; private set;}        
}
```

Usage:

```
new Person("jordan");
```

Or `private` fields, also set in constructor (same usage).

```
class Person
{
    private string surname;

    public Person(string surname)
    {
       this.surname = surname;
    }

    public string Surname {get{return surname;}}        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set private property in constructor like this:

```
public class person
{
    private string name { get; set; };
    public string surname { get; set; };
    private int year { get; set; };

    public person(string name, int year)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
    }
}
public class student : person
{
    public student(string name, int year) : base (name, year) { };
}
```

and use can be:

```
list.Add(new student("name", 45)
{
    surname = "jordan"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the fields are private you can provide public properties. You should do that anyway since the fields should not be accessible from outside, all the more if they are just backing fields for properties.

```
class person
{
    private string name;
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private string surname;
    public string Surname
    {
        get { return surname; }
        set { surname = value; }
    }

    private int year;
    public int Year
    {
        get { return year; }
        private set { year = value; }
    }
}
```

Now the fields are private and you can change the access modifiers of the properties according to your needs. You can even make the setter private as shown in the `Year` property.

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
list.Add(new Person()
{
    Name = "Michael",
    Surname = "jordan",
});
```

Now you cannot modify the `Year` from outside since it's `private`. You could provide an appropriate constructor to initialize it.